# TabControl event SelectionChanged performed twice when change on identical item

Tags: c#, wpf

In my program i create dynamically TabItems, and i can create a few the same items. Problem is when i am switching from one to second the same items. In this moment event:

```
private void TabCards_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Source is TabControl)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

run 2 times. I could give Stopwatch and block run this event twice time in a short period of time. But i dont think it is good solution.

Maybe have someone idea what can i do?

Edit

This is how i add item:

```
private void AddTabItemForCard(string cardName)
    {
        var style = (Style)resources.FindResource("Style" + cardName);
        var tabItem = new TabItem
        {
            Style = style,
            Header = cardName
        };
        TabCards.Items.Add(tabItem);
    }
```

This is TabControl in xaml:

```
<TabControl x:Name="TabCards" Grid.Column="1" SelectionChanged="TabCards_SelectionChanged" >
    </TabControl>
```

And style:

```
        <Style x:Key="StyleWej" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True"/>
        <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseMove" Handler="TabItem_PreviewMouseMove"/>
        <EventSetter Event="Drop" Handler="TabItem_Drop"/>
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Adres(hex)" FontSize="15" Margin="10,10,396,444"/>
                        <ComboBox x:Name="AddressWej" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="134,11,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
                            <ComboBoxItem>30</ComboBoxItem>
                            <ComboBoxItem>31</ComboBoxItem>
                            <ComboBoxItem>32</ComboBoxItem>
                        </ComboBox>

                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Wejscie 1:" FontSize="15" Margin="10,126,396,337"/>
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Wejscie 2:" FontSize="15" Margin="10,156,396,307"/>

                        <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Wejscie1" Width="120" Margin="134,129,231,331"/>
                        <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Wejscie2" Width="120" Margin="134,157,231,302"/>

                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Events:

```
 private void TabItem_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(e.Source is TabItem tabItem))
            return;

        if (Mouse.PrimaryDevice.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(tabItem, tabItem, DragDropEffects.All);
        }
    }
    private void TabItem_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        var tabItemTarget = e.Source as TabItem;

        var tabItemSource = e.Data.GetData(typeof(TabItem)) as TabItem;

        if (!tabItemTarget.Equals(tabItemSource))
        {
            var tabControl = tabItemTarget.Parent as TabControl;
            int sourceIndex = tabControl.Items.IndexOf(tabItemSource);
            int targetIndex = tabControl.Items.IndexOf(tabItemTarget);

            tabControl.Items.Remove(tabItemSource);
            tabControl.Items.Insert(targetIndex, tabItemSource);

            tabControl.Items.Remove(tabItemTarget);
            tabControl.Items.Insert(sourceIndex, tabItemTarget);
        }
    }
```

And in TabCards_SelectionChanged i check with TabItem is it and run:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject rootObject) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (rootObject != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(rootObject); i++)
            {
                DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(rootObject, i);

                if (child != null && child is T)
                    yield return (T)child;

                foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
                    yield return childOfChild;
            }
        }
    }
```

to find all TextBox from TabItem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xZEx.png)

Comment: Please provide more info. Are you shure that you not add this handler twice to one control?

Comment: Yes i am sure, because when i change the same item with other different item it isnt happen.

Comment: Could you provide full code

Comment: I added all code tied with this.

Comment: can you put a breakpoint inside TabCards_SelectionChanged and check out what is the sender and e? For selectionchange it should triggered twice, 1 for deselect the previous 1 for select the current, but this i  not sure isit applied to the tabitem too

Comment: It is the same i added photo. Sender to is always the same

Comment: i actually copy all the code you write into a new project, and it wont triggered twice even it is the same name.. so can you show us  what you do  in TabItem_PreviewMouseMove, TabItem_Drop and TabCards_SelectionChanged? did you change the selected item in any of this event?

Comment: I added code from this first two events, from thrid i check which card is it and assigns text to TextBox, but it dont work good yet. And do it only in case I change cards between the identical tabitems. Which in turn causes a double start error.

Comment: try remove all the event function content, and try to make selectionchanged do nothing and check will it still fire twice?

Comment: i noticed that if we drag and drop the tab it will fire the event alot of time depends on how many tab you have

Comment: I implement this events but i dont use it yet for drag. But really when i coments "textBoxesCard = FindVisualChildren<TextBox>(TabCards).ToList();
                        addressCard = FindVisualChildren<ComboBox>(TabCards).ToList().FirstOrDefault();" in event TabCards_SelectionChanged, it didnt run twice time. So problem is with this funkcion. Now I realized i run this funkcion when page probably isnt initialize yet. so maybe it is problem. Thanks you rly for help.

Comment: Ok glad it helps.. you can add this.isloaded checking in selectionchanged to prevent d  code from running be4 the page is initialized.